# Cart Price Rules: Minimum Purchase of 2 of the same items to get 15% discount

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, discount

I am trying to set up the following rule in Price Cart Rules:

> Promotion: 15% off selected products with minimum purchase of 2 items and above.

**Criteria:** No combined purchased allowed, meaning, discount will only be given if two or more of the same item is purchased.

**Example:**

```
SKU1 (Configurable Product)

Inside SKU1 contains the following simple products:

SKU1-1 (Product 1)

SKU1-2 (Product 2)

SKU1-3 (Product 3)

SKU1-4 (ProIuct 4)
```

**This promotion code must work if i purchase 2 or more of SKU1-1. How do i achieve this?**

Am aware that the minimum quantity can be adjusted in the product page settings, however, we would also want to give customers the option to purchase 1 item instead of forcing them to buy 2 to get the discount.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for setting cart price rule. 
[image]
[image]